# Attempt to present which is already presenting

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit

All I wand to do is to invoke new controller over the current context when I'm touching for a long time(UILongPressGestureRecognizer).
Here the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!{
    didSet{
        button.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                                 action: #selector(settingTheButton(_:))))
    }
}

func settingTheButton(_ recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    print("touchTheColorButton was called") // here the method invokes twice
    if let button = recognizer.view as? UIButton{
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "setTheButtonColor", sender: button)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier == "setTheButtonColor", let vc = segue.destination as? SettingsForButtonVC, let senderButton = sender as? UIButton {
        vc.button = senderButton
    }
}
}
```

I don't understand. Why has the method settingTheButton invoked twice? It doesn't interfere or harm a program but it really disturb me.

Console:
**touchTheColorButton was called
touchTheColorButton was called
2017-02-18 01:28:12.499552 Test[1042:223223] Warning: Attempt to present   on  which is already presenting**

Comment: Change the segue's sender to self, and delete your prepareForSegue method's button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the solution given by @Marco Santarossa (can't comment). This will work correctly:

```
func settingTheButton(_ recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

    // Get the button just as you have done
    if let button = recognizer.view as? UIButton{

        // Take only the `.ended` event, discarding any other ones
        if recognizer.state == .ended {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "setTheButtonColor", sender: button)
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with your code is that `settingTheButton(_ recognizer:)` is called once per every time an event is triggered in the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, not just when releasing the button which is the behavior you probably expect. The two events are `.began` (once the press has been recognized as a long press) and `.ended` (after releasing the long press).

Simply ignoring on the two will make your code be called just once, additionally it makes more sense on `.ended` due to the fact that you probably want the new screen to appear after releasing the button instead of during the button press.

NOTE: Just so you know, it's better to specifically only allow `.ended` since there is at least one other common event that can be triggered apart from those two that I know of. If you are on a force touch device, `.changed` will be called many times, once for each extremely slight change of pressure that is made.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're not listening the state of the gesture.

Change to:

```
func settingTheButton(_ recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    guard recognizer.state == .ended else { return }

    print("touchTheColorButton was called") // here the method invokes twice
    if let button = recognizer.view as? UIButton{
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "setTheButtonColor", sender: button)
    }
}
```

I didn't test properly. Let me know if it doesn't work before downvoting.